# Как правильно создать динамический массив Mas[100][100]?

Tags: c++

И как удалить его после использования?

Comment: создание:

    vector< vector<int> > v(100, vector<int>(100));

удалится он сам, когда выйдет из области видимости.

Answer (score 1):

[Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
создение массива. Type- это тип массива(int,char,float,double и т.д.)
mas=new Type* [100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
mas[i]=new Type [100];

удаление массива
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
delete mas[i];
delete mas;
```

Comment: Это не динамический массив, а динамическое выделение памяти.

"Динамическим называется массив, размер которого может меняться во время исполнения программы."

Comment: В C++ не рекомендуется использовать нативные массивы, они — [зло](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html).